# Difficulties while querying with LINQ Many to Many (MTM) association

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

IMHO, I think this is the hardest thing for me to get - the whole MTM side of LINQ and I need help.

In SQL I have 3 tables: `Accounts`, `AccountsInFeatures` and `Features`. `AccountsInFeatures` simply has two primary key columns that link to `Accounts` to `Features`.

In EF, `AccountsInFeatures` is not visible - I understand why - but I'm having problems creating the LINQ:

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
return (from a in _Store.Accounts
        where a.AccountGUID == _AccountGUID
        select new AccountDetails
        {
            AccountGUID = a.AccountGUID
            AccountName = a.AccountName,
            SelectedFeatures = a.Features.Select(f => f.FeatureGUID).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Here's the definition for `AccountDetails`:

```
public class AccountDetails
{
    public Guid AccountGUID { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }  
    public List<Guid> SelectedFeatures { get; set; }    
}
```

How do I fill `"SelectedFeatures"` with a list of Features - is this possible? I'm close to just splitting this into two queries =)

Comment: By the way, what you mean with MTM? Just curious...

Comment: OK... I thought about that. :) I'm used to M x M notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
public class AccountDetails
{
    public Guid AccountGUID { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }  
    public Collection<Features> SelectedFeatures { get; set; }    
}
```

and

```
return (from a in _Store.Accounts
        where a.AccountGUID == _AccountGUID
        select new AccountDetails
        {
            AccountGUID = a.AccountGUID
            AccountName = a.AccountName,
            SelectedFeatures = a.Features
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this and it won't compile: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Features>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Features>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)      --- I also tried adding ToList(), but that gave me a simliar conversion error.

Comment: Just replace `List<Features> SelectedFeatures` with `Collection<Features> SelectedFeatures`.